# Using PHP how do I include Saturday into my business days?

Tags: php, date

I've managed to get the following code to work for 'weekdays' and exclude my special days, however:

I'm offering a '7 business days no deposit layby' though my shop is only closed on Sundays. So I need my 'weekday' to include all Saturday's.

```
$tdate = date("Y-m-d");
$specialdays = ['22-09-2017', '03-10-2017', '14-11-2017', '17-12-2017'];
$i = 7;
$sevenbusinessdays = date('d-m-Y', strtotime($tdate . ' +' . $i . ' 
Weekday'));

while (in_array($sevenbusinessdays, $specialdays)) {
   $i++;
   $sevenbusinessdays = date('d-m-Y', strtotime($tdate . ' +' . $i . ' Weekday'));
}
```

I believe using the above code the answer is something to do with

```
date('w', strtotime($tdate)) == 6
```

Though I'm unsure how to incorporate it. I've tried the following but it's not working:

```
$tdate = date("Y-m-d");
$specialdays = ['22-09-2017', '03-10-2017', '14-11-2017', '17-12-2017'];
$i = 7;
$sevenbusinessdays = date('d-m-Y', strtotime($tdate . ' +' . $i . ' Weekday' . date('w', strtotime($tdate)) == '6'));

while (in_array($sevenbusinessdays, $specialdays)) {
    $i++;
    $sevenbusinessdays = date('d-m-Y', strtotime($tdate . ' +' . $i . ' Weekday' . date('w', strtotime($tdate)) == '6'));
}

print $sevenbusinessdays;
```

This completely failed haha, any guidance and help would be greatly appreciated. I think I'm close, just not getting it.

Thanks for any help, it's greatly appreciated it. :-)

Comment: What are you trying to do? I can't see what you are trying to do. And what are those special days? What is the input, and what is the output, and expected output.

Comment: @Andreas sorry I forgot to include that $tdate was a preset date. Either way ishegg gave me a working example that makes sense. Thanks for your reply Andreas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to to a loop, adding days if:

- it's not a sunday OR
- it's not in the special days list

until you've added 7 days

```
<?php
$tdate = date("Y-m-d");
$specialdays = ['15-09-2017', '20-09-2017', '14-11-2017', '17-12-2017'];
$days = 0;
$i = 0;
while ($days < 7) {
    $i++;
    $day = strtotime($tdate . ' +' . $i . ' day');
    if (date("w", $day) === "0" || in_array(date("d-m-Y", $day), $specialdays)) {
        continue;
    }
    $days++;
}
$sevenbusinessdays = date('d-m-Y', strtotime($tdate . ' +' . $i . ' day'));
echo $sevenbusinessdays;
```

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/FUqub)

Comment: Why are you updating the `$sevenbusinessdays` variable on every iteration?